# Why can I not break from a `while` loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why Ruby doesn't break from this `while` loop:

```
i = nil
while true
  i = gets
  if i == 5
    break
  end
  puts i
end
```

Please explain the reason.

Comment: I think you should use 'then' after 'If' condition:

Comment: Do you think like this code

Comment: <pre>i=nil
while true do
i=gets
if i==5 then
    break
end
puts i

end </pre>

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan You don't need it unless the conditional statement is on one line

Comment: I just add "then" after 'if' but code can not break while loop

Comment: Clue: When you do `gets` what type of object that you get? And what type of Object you're comparing it with in your condition?

Answer (score 7):

Your code doesn't work because your loop is checking for `i == 5`, but `gets` will always return the user's input as a string. So if input is `5`, `gets` will return it as `"5"`, it won't convert it to `5` which is required for the break. You need to convert the input from a string to a number. Use [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) on your user input and your code will work as desired.

```
i = nil
while true
  i = gets.to_i
  if i == 5
    break
  end
  puts i
end
```

You could also introduce a second variable `j` used for checking if the input is `5` and to preserve `i`. This is so that if the user's input is a letter, the letter will be printed to the screen instead of `0`:

```
while true
  i = gets.chomp
  j = i.to_i
  if j == 5
    break
  end
  puts i
end
```

Another way is to use a [`Kernel#loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop):

```
loop do
  i = gets.chomp
  j = i.to_i
  break if j == 5
  puts i
end
```

Another way is to use an [`until`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop) loop:

```
j = 1
until j == 5
  i = gets.chomp
  j = i.to_i
  puts i
end
```

Comment: And, the most straightforward way would be to just compare an input against string: `loop do (i = gets.chomp) == '5' ? (break i) : (puts i) end`.

Comment: @mudasobwa ah yes much much better.